# Accidently deleted Windows, have Ubuntu installed but can't run

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

So this is my problem:

I put Ubuntu on a USB stick with the usual method. I then restarted my computer and went into the BIOS menu (HP press F10) and switched USB to the top of the boot order. It then showed the GRUB menu that comes with Ubuntu. I selected install Ubuntu. After that, I went through the installation dialog and selected overwrite all other operating systems. It successfully installed after that.

After restarting, it shows GRUB again (If I unplug USB it shows no OS found). So I went to BIOS and put the newly created Ubuntu option to the top. I saved it all and went back to BIOS and it went back to the bottom. What? If I change boot order to anything else at top it will save. But not with this.

I would appreciate any help...

Comment: Please try not to use inappropriate language http://superuser.com/help/be-nice

Comment: What are you exactly asking? Are you attempting to get your Windows installation back (which doesn't sound quite possible), or to boot Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

> After that, I went through the installation dialog and selected
>   overwrite all other operating systems

Here is where you killed your bootmgr which was probably on one of those partitions. Install Ubuntu again to get a functioning Grub.